# mayavi points3d renering incorectly

Tags: python, 3d, mayavi.mlab

I have code like this:

```
import mayavi.mlab as mlab
import numpy as np
import random 

#white blackground
mlab.figure(fgcolor=(0., 0., 0.), bgcolor=(1, 1, 1))

x1 = y1 = z1 = size1 = []
# number of points
number = 21
for i in range(1,number):
        x1.append(random.randint(-10,11))
        y1.append(random.randint(-10,11))
        z1.append(random.randint(-10,11))
        size1.append(i)

#create spheres
mlab.points3d(x1, y1, z1, size1, resolution=30)
#render
mlab.show()
```

And the result renders with more points, than 20:
[image]

What I am doing incorrectly? Why spheres are not in random positions and the numbers of spheres?
When `number == 2`, the render is with 3 spheres:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it!
First mistake is:

```
x1 = y1 = z1 = size1 = []
```

It should be:

```
x1 = []
y1 = []
z1 = []
size1 = []
```

And it is better to add `scale_factor=1` in `mlab.points3d`